# Prevent interception in RabbitMQ when sending messages from one user to another

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I recently started using rabbitmq. in front end i use SockJS + Stomp. In rabbitmq I create exchange "messages" with type "topic". In time of connection Stomp create queue like amq.gen-Uf_bUS-5GG3WyzOn_avMig and subscribe to "messages". I can not understand access rights.

Consider a simple action. One user sends a message to another. How to make sure that access to this message in the rabbitmq have only this two users?

Or for example, I need to send a system message to only one user. How to make that this message was available only for this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AMQP any inside single vhost any queue can be bounded to any exchange, so any AMQO user that has access rights to read from queue can get message from queue and read it (and possibly put it back when using manual acknowledge and not ack'ing received message).

If AMQP user has configure/write rights than it potentially have access to any entity, incl. messages in vhost.

For details how permissions works see [Access Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) RabbitMQ manual.

In general, it's not good idea to move access control from application level to AMQP broker one. If you want something keep visible to special users inside your application, just do in in application level. Your application users and RabbitMQ users are not quite the same. RabbitMQ users are somehow like MySQL users: they fits to special needs, nothing more.